# arrows up and down don't work with userEvent

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library, html-input, user-event

I'm handling a test on input type number, where I expect increase and decrease value when typing on keyboard arrow up and down respectively. The Issue is that nothing happens, the input value remains the same. Someone could look into my code and see what is happening. I believe that userEvent and input are not communicating with each other in this particular event

```js
it('renders current year', () => {
  render(
    <input
      type="number"
      step="1"
      name="number"
      placeholder="number"
      aria-label="number"
      defaultValue={0}
    />
  );
  const input = screen.getByPlaceholderText(/number/i);
  user.type(input, '{arrowup}');
  console.log(input);
  expect(input).toHaveValue(1);
});
```

Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/late-http-ff27ln?file=/src/App.test.tsx

Comment: Looks like there is an issue for that: https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/issues/1066 One thing - since version 14 whole API of userEvent is `async` so you need to use `await`.

Comment: Even with async await it is not possible, it seems that testing library don't support user event handling yet. I've made a request for them to look into it

Comment: `{arrowup}` and `{arrowdown}` does work. I think the missing piece is that you're only selecting the input, but you're not focusing on it before mocking the arrow keys. Try adding `input.focus();` before your `{arrowup}` command.

Answer (score 2):

instead of

```
user.type(input, '{arrowup}');
```

try

```
await user.keyboard('[ArrowUp]')
```

On a side note, it is recommended to access the element by role if possible, to ensure accessibility. Hence, instead of:

```
const input = screen.getByPlaceholderText(/number/i);
```

try

```
const input = screen.getByRole('textbox');
```

Comment: It helped thanks (docs is unclear on keyboard keys IMHO)